# Why can MaxValue simply not get the exact result I want?

Tags: maximum

`8/7 (9 + 4 Sqrt[2])` That's the result I want.

*How can I get x and y at the same time with respect to max?*

**How can I add the constraint that both x and y belong to `Reals`?**

*That's the result I want here*

```
MaxValue[{x^2 - x*y + 2*y^2 == 8 && x^2 + x*y + 2 y^2}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: According to the documentation, first you provide the function to maximize and then the constraints. `MaxValue[{f,cons},{x,y}]` gives the maximum value of f subject to the constraints cons. Are you sure the order does not matter?

Comment: First, change `&&` to a coma. You'll get an error saying you should - as yarchik points out - first give the function, then the constraints. When you do so, you'll get a `Root` expression, which you can `FullSimplify` to obtain the desired answer.

Comment: @corey979, Thanks for your comment. But how can add both {x,y} belongs to Reals   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like yarchik says, you just have to put the first argument in the right form for this to work:

```
MaxValue[{x^2 + x*y + 2 y^2, x^2 - x*y + 2*y^2 == 8}, {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

> 8/7 (9 + 4 Sqrt[2])

`FullSimplify` was also needed to get the same expression that you mentioned.

Comment: How about x and y with respect to max?

Comment: If you want to get the values of `x` and `y`, use `Maximize` instead of `MaxValue`. If you want to constrain the values to be real, append `&& x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals` to the constraint.

Comment: `Simplify[Maximize[{x^2 + x*y + 2 y^2, 
   x^2 - x*y + 2*y^2 == 8, {x, y} \[Element] Reals}, {x, y}]]` How about this?

Comment: @kile That is not a documented form of the arguments. If you want to be sure that things work, do as it says in the documentation: `{form, cons}`. The first element is the form, the second element is the constraint. Your list has three elements. You can also consider using the third argument for this: `Maximize[{
  x^2 + x*y + 2 y^2,
  x^2 - x*y + 2*y^2 == 8
  }, {x, y}, Reals]`

Comment: `FullSimplify[
 Solve[x^2 - x*y + 2*y^2 == 8 && x == -2 Sqrt[2/7 (4 + Sqrt[2])], {x, 
   y}, Reals]]` why did we have 2 different y when you replace x with `-2 Sqrt[2/7 (4 + Sqrt[2])]`?

Comment: @kile That's an unrelated question.